# How to put UI Element always on the top in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, z-index, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am working on UWP app which has few views and a banner ad view. I want the banner ad view to be on the top always, it should not hide behind any other elements.

**My setup:**
I have a stack panel in which there are other elements and the banner is added programmatically as shown in the below snippets.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stckPnl" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBox x:Name="plcTextbox" Header="PLACEMENT:" Text="123456" TextAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="0,40,0,0" Height="60" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="loadBannerBtn" Content="Load Banner" Click="LoadBanner" 
                Margin="0,40,0,0" Height="40" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingIndicator" 
                Margin="0,40,0,0" Height="40" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Chocolate" Opacity="0.5" Canvas.ZIndex="40" Margin="20"/>
</Grid>
```

And I am adding banner as below

```
_banner = new Banner(plcTextbox.Text.Trim(), AdSize.Banner320x50);
_banner.Margin = new Thickness(0, 40, 0, 0);
_banner.LoadAd();
Canvas.SetZIndex(_banner, 30000);
stckPnl.Children.Add(_banner);
```

**What I have tried so far**
I have tried setting z-index on the canvas like `Canvas.SetZIndex(_banner, 30000);` but it doesn't work. Even after adding the z-index, the semi-transparent rectangle is shown on the top and the banner gets hidden behind it. When I add z-index on the stack panel > z-index of the semi-transparent rectangle then only the banner is shown on the top.

[image]

What should I do to have the banner always on the top irrespective of the parent or siblings of the parent?

Comment: I've provided an answer, kindly accept, if you find it right too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index works only works for elements within panel elements - thus, even if you set 30000, it would only work for `StackPanel` in which it is added. And since the `Rectangle` is added after `StackPanel` it would continue to be on the top.

The solution for you would be to add `Rectangle` before `StackPanel` or take `Banner` object out of `StackPanel`

Answer (score 2):

The `Grid` control puts the children elements on top of another respecting the ascending order by which they are declared in XAML.
You put the `Rectangle` **AFTER** the `StackPanel`... it means that the `StackPanel` itself will always be behind the `Rectangle`.

Best regards

Comment: So what should I do to keep my banner on the top always